# Wagtail Page prevent asking parent page

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-streamfield

I dont like this step, I want to add page and there should not be any parent or child. it will stand alone a page only.

Like when i click on creating a page from `wagtail hooks` or wagtail `snippet` it should direct redirect me to content creating panels instead of asking parent or child like this page.

I dont want my page should have any parent or child. and even i hate this step of asking parent page.

I have addeed this variable there but yet it showing this steps.

```
class ListingPage(Page):
   
    parent_page_type = []
    subpage_types = [
    ]
```

Can anyone help me to get rid of this section?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pages need to have a parent - the page tree structure determines the URL that a page will have, so if there's no parent, it will never be possible to reach that page at any URL.

However, if a new page has *exactly one* possible parent, then this choice screen will be skipped. For example, if you set `parent_page_types = ['home.HomePage']` and only one HomePage exists in your site structure, then it will skip this prompt and take the user straight to the editing view (which will then create a page as a child of the homepage).